# Passing both String and JSON object in POSTMAN (REST client)

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, postman

I have created my springboot application which accepts a '**String**' and a '**JSONObject**' as input.

I have tried passing passing them using the **Params** then entering the key & value like,

```
Name XYZ
Status {
    "A": ["12", "11", "21"],
    "B": ["AA", "BB", "CC"],
    "C": ["AAA"]
}
```

But, I get "argument type mismatch\nHandlerMethod details"

```
{
  "timestamp": 1490697361238,
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "java.lang.IllegalStateException",
  "message": "argument type mismatch\nHandlerMethod details: \nController [processing.QueryController]\nMethod [public static java.lang.String preprocessing.QueryController.abcMethod(java.lang.String,org.json.simple.JSONObject) throws java.io.IOException,org.json.simple.parser.ParseException]\nResolved arguments: \n[0] [type=java.lang.String] [value=TEMPA]\n[1] [type=org.springframework.validation.support.BindingAwareModelMap] [value={}]\n",
  "path": "/Preprocessor/Load"
}
```

Comment: Can you show source of method `abcMethod` and curl of your http request?

Answer (score 0):

You can always @RequestParam or @PathVariable to send the String and @RequestBody to send the JSON.

If you are not getting what I just told. Share your REST service code I will explain in details.